# Increment in Laravel collection

Tags: php, loops, collections, increment, laravel-5.7

I have a collection and I would like to increment values if the condition is met. I want to use `map()` method to iterate and return array (or collection) with total counts. So far I have this:

```
   $counts = [
        'notChecked' => 0,
        'published' => 0,
        'total' => 0
    ];

    $this->reviewPhotosRepository->getByHotelId($hotel_id)->map(function($photo) use (&$counts) {
        $photo->checked ?: $counts['notChecked']++;
        $photo->published ?: $counts['published']++;
        $counts['total']++;
    });

    return $counts;
```

It works but I think it looks quite odd and it is not such a 'laravelish' way. Is there any other option to look it a little better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `map()`, you could use `reduce()`:

```
return $this->reviewPhotosRepository
    ->getByHotelId($hotel_id)
    ->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
        $carry['notChecked'] += $item['checked'] ? 1 : 0;
        $carry['published'] += $item['published'] ? 1 : 0;
        $carry['total'] += 1;
        return $carry;
    }, [
        'notChecked' => 0,
        'published' => 0,
        'total' => 0
    ]);
```

Is it better? Well, you know, that's just, like, your opinion, man.